# How to construct proper JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, casperjs

I have the following javascript code I use with casperjs to iterate some links and return some data in json format.

Here is my snippet

```
casper.each(links, function (self, link) {

this.thenOpen(link, function () {
    //get work order info
    var town_selector = 'div tr';
    var town_names_info = this.getElementsInfo(town_selector);
    var town_names = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < town_names_info.length; i++) {
        town_names.push(town_names_info[i].text.trim().replace(/\n\s+\n/, ''));
    }
    var jsonTest = arrayToObject(town_names);
    json.push(JSON.stringify(jsonTest));
    casper.capture('./images/workOrder' + workOrder + '.png');
    workOrder++
    utils.dump(jsonTest);
    array.push(jsonTest);
    casper.thenClick(x('/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[2]'), function () {
        //more some stuff here 
        someLinks = this.evaluate(getLinks);

        for (var i = 0; i < someLinks.length; i++) {
            someLinks[i] = "https://somelink" + someLinks[i];
        }
        casper.each(someLinks, function (self, link) {
            self.thenOpen(link, function () {
                var selector = 'div tr';
                var names_info = this.getElementsInfo(town_selector);
                var names = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < names_info.length; i++) {
                    names.push(names_info[i].text.trim().replace(/\n\s+\n/, ''));
                }
                var jsonTest = arrayToObject(names);
                json.push(JSON.stringify(jsonTest));
                utils.dump(jsonTest);
                array.push(jsonTest);
                fs.write('results.json', JSON.stringify(array), 'w');
                casper.capture('./images/lineItem' + lineItem + '.png');
                lineItem++
            });
         });
      });
   });
});
```

The following would be the output for two activities with two line items each.

```
    [{"Activity #":"some activity",
      "Customer":"some customer",
      "Account #":"some account"},
     {
      "Line #":"1",
      "Action Required":"",
      "Status":"some status",
      "Product Line":"some product line",
      "Product":"some product"},
     {
      "Line #":"2",
      "Action Required":"",
      "Status":"some status",
      "Product Line":"some product line",
      "Product":"some product"},
     {
      "Activity #":"some other activity",
      "Customer":"some other customer",
      "Account #":"some other account"},
     {
      "Line #":"1",
      "Action Required":"",
      "Status":"some status",
      "Product Line":"some product line",
      "Product":"some product"},
     {
      "Line #":"2",
      "Action Required":"",
      "Status":"some status",
      "Product Line":"some product line",
      "Product":"some product"}]
```

Can someone please help me get my output to look like this instead?

```
    [{
        "Activity #": "some activity",
        "Customer": "some customer",
        "Account #": "some account",
        "lineItems": [
            {
                "Line #": "1",
                "Action Required": "",
                "Status": "some status",
                "Product Line": "some product line",
                "Product": "some product"
            },
            {
                "Line #": "2",
                "Action Required": "",
                "Status": "some status",
                "Product Line": "some product line",
                "Product": "some product"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Activity #": "some activity",
        "Customer": "some customer",
        "Account #": "some account",
        "lineItems": [
            {
                "Line #": "1",
                "Action Required": "",
                "Status": "some status",
                "Product Line": "some product line",
                "Product": "some product"
            },
            {
                "Line #": "2",
                "Action Required": "",
                "Status": "some status",
                "Product Line": "some product line",
                "Product": "some product"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: WTH is `json` and `jsonTest`?

Comment: sorry. maybe this could help. `//arrayToObject
    function arrayToObject(arr) {
        var out = {};
        arr.forEach(function (element) {
            var keyvalue = element;
            var key = keyvalue.substring(0, element.indexOf(':'));
            var value = keyvalue.substring(key.length + 1).trim();
            out[key] = value;
        });
        return out;
    }`

Comment: okay, but what are you using them for?

Comment: I push the date i get with casper to them.

Comment: And then? I don't see `json` used in your code again.

Comment: I will go ahead and delete that variable but I don't think I has anything to do with my output.

Answer (score 0):

Using the appropriate arguments to [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) should do it:

```
fs.write('results.json', JSON.stringify(array, null, 4), 'w');
```

Comment: my output is the same as before with your method.